# Integrating wrt y first and x first gives different answers.

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, definite-integrals

I am solving trying to solve for the CDF of 
$$f(x,y)=2(x+y) , 0  \leq x \leq y \leq 1$$
I am doing it this way$$\int_{x}^{y} \bigg(\int_{0}^{x}2(x+y)dx \bigg) dy$$

And this way
$$ \int_{0}^{x}\bigg(\int_{x}^{y}2(x+y)dy \bigg) dx$$

But they  are giving me different answers.
$$\int_{x}^{y} \bigg(\int_{0}^{x}2(x+y)dx \bigg) dy=x^2y+xy^2-2x^3 $$

And $$ \int_{0}^{x}\bigg(\int_{x}^{y}2(x+y)dy \bigg) dx=-x^3+x^2y+xy^2$$
The last one is given as the answer in the book. Why is it not working both ways? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks confusing when the variable wrt which you are integrating is in the integral limits.

Comment: This is not well defined. As mentioned by Stubborn atom you can't have $x$ both in integrand and limit and "$d$"

Comment: Try to rewrite $x \leq y$ into a variable change.

Comment: @StubbornAtom , What if I just integrate it like-
$$F(x,y)= \int_\int_f(a,b)dadb=\int_{x}^{y} \bigg(\int_{0}^{x}2(a+b)da \bigg) db$$ , The variable wrt to which I am integrating is not in the integral limits, but if I integrate wrt a first, I get a different asnwer than when I integrate wrt to b first

Comment: $$F(x,y)= \int_{}^{}\int_{}^{}f(a,b)dadb=\int_{x}^{y} \bigg(\int_{0}^{x}2(a+b)da \bigg)db$$ I'm sorry, this is what the code above looks like

Comment: @RohanChatterjee You should get the same answer, as I indicated in the answer below. Limits of your integrals are not correct.

Answer (score 1):

For every $(a,b)\in\mathbb R^2$, distribution function of $(X,Y)$ is

\begin{align}
P(X\le a,Y\le b)&=E\left[\mathbf1_{X\le a,Y\le b}\right]
\\&=\iint \mathbf1_{x\le a, y\le b}\,f(x,y)\,dx\,dy
\\&=2\iint \mathbf1_{x\le a, y\le b}(x+y)\mathbf1_{0\le x\le y\le 1}\,dx\,dy
\\&=2\int_0^{\min(b,1)}\left(\int_0^{\min(a,y)}(x+y)\,dx\right)dy
\end{align}

If you want to integrate wrt $y$ first, then the last step becomes $$2\int_0^{\min(a,1)}\left(\int_{x}^{\min(b,1)}(x+y)\,dy\right)dx$$